# Dynamically add a row to an Angular 5 Material Form

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I am using Angular Material to design a basic form, but I am stuck with trying to create the functionality to add a dynamic row to the form. I.e., when I click an "add" button next to a row, it should add a new empty row.

I have tried numerous ways to make use of this example, but my data either repeats, or my list bombs out:

**The form code:**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Code</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let field of fieldArray; let i = index">
      <td>
        <input [(ngModel)]="field.code" class="form-control" type="text" name="{{field.code}}" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input [(ngModel)]="field.name" class="form-control" type="text" name="{{field.name}}" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input [(ngModel)]="field.price" class="form-control" type="text" name="{{field.price}}" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <button mat-raised-button class="form-button-spacing" color="warn" type="button" (click)="deleteFieldValue(i)">
          Delete</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="newAttributeCode" [(ngModel)]="newAttribute.code" name="newAttributeCode" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="newAttributeName" [(ngModel)]="newAttribute.name" name="newAttributeName" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="newAttributePrice" [(ngModel)]="newAttribute.price" name="newAttributePrice"
        />
      </td>
      <td>

        <button mat-raised-button class="form-button-spacing" color="primary" type="button" (click)="addFieldValue()">
          Add</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**The component code:**

```
private fieldArray: Array<any> = [];
private newAttribute: any = {};


addFieldValue() {
  this.fieldArray.push(this.newAttribute)
  this.newAttribute = {};
}

deleteFieldValue(index) {
  this.fieldArray.splice(index, 1);
}
```

**How can I use my code below to create the same dynamically added rows:**

```
<mat-expansion-panel [expanded]="step === 4" (opened)="setStep(4)" hideToggle="true">
<mat-expansion-panel-header>
  <mat-panel-title>
    <h4>Permits</h4>
  </mat-panel-title>
  <mat-panel-description>
    <div></div>
    <mat-icon>whatshot</mat-icon>
  </mat-panel-description>
</mat-expansion-panel-header>

<div class="form">
  <form class="permits-form" #permitsForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)=onSubmit(permitsForm)>
    <input type="hidden" name="AssetID" #AssetID="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="assetDataService.selectedAsset.AssetID">
    <table class="full-width" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <mat-form-field>
            <mat-select placeholder="Permits" id="Permits" name="Permits" #Permits="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="assetDataService.selectedAsset.Permits"
              required>
              <mat-option *ngFor="let permit of permits" [value]="permit.name" required>
                {{ permit.name }}
              </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
          </mat-form-field>
        </td>
        <td>
          <mat-form-field class="full-width">
            <input matInput placeholder="Title of Permit" id="PermitTitle" name="PermitTitle" #PermitTitle="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="assetDataService.selectedAsset.PermitTitle"
              required>
          </mat-form-field>
        </td>
        <td>
          <mat-form-field class="full-width">
            <input matInput [matDatepicker]="PermitIssueDate" placeholder="Issue Date" id="PermitIssueDate" name="PermitIssueDate" #PermitIssueDate="ngModel"
              [(ngModel)]="assetDataService.selectedAsset.PermitIssueDate" required>
            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="PermitIssueDate"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
            <mat-datepicker touchUi="true" #PermitIssueDate></mat-datepicker>
          </mat-form-field>
        </td>
        <td>
          <mat-form-field class="full-width">
            <input matInput [matDatepicker]="PermitEndDate" placeholder="Expiry Date" id="PermitEndDate" name="PermitEndDate" #PermitEndDate="ngModel"
              [(ngModel)]="assetDataService.selectedAsset.PermitEndDate">
            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="PermitEndDate"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
            <mat-datepicker touchUi="true" #PermitEndDate></mat-datepicker>
          </mat-form-field>
        </td>
        <td>
          <mat-icon>add_circle_outline</mat-icon>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: you are not using *ngFor at tr level, you are just using it at options

Comment: Yes, I know. I added my working vanilla code, without me buggering it up with loops. I simply need to know how to use i = index and to assign dynamic values to newly created components etc. I think... :|

Comment: We can help you only if you provide us with what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I was able to resolve my need by implementing the following:**

**First, in my view I created another `mat-table` to hold and loop my added lines, as well as fetch the data source and assigning it to the table:**

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="getPermitDataSource()">

  <!-- Id Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="permit">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Permit </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let permit"> {{permit.Permits}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Make Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="title">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Permet Title </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let permit"> {{permit.PermitTitle}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Model Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="issue">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Issue Date </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let permit"> {{permit.PermitIssueDate | date}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Regitration Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="expiry">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Expiry Date </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let permit"> {{permit.PermitEndDate | date}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- actions -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Edit | Delete</mat-header-cell>

    <mat-action-row>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let permit; let i=index;">
        <button mat-icon-button class="form-button-spacing float-right" color="primary" (click)="onPermitDelete(permitsForm)">
          <mat-icon aria-label="Delete">delete</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </mat-cell>
    </mat-action-row>

  </ng-container>

  <!-- <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row> -->
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

**Secondly, I implemented the functionality in my component:**

```
addNewPermitToArray(form: NgForm) {
    this.permitArray.push(form.value);
    this.getPermitDataSource();
    form.reset();
}

getPermitDataSource() {
    this.displayedColumns = this.displayedColumns = ['permit', 'title', 'issue', 'expiry', 'actions'];
    return this.permitDataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.permitArray);
}
```

I hope this will help someone else out there!

Answer (score 0):

You should use reactive forms and you can add form controls dynamically.